# Ibeacons core Location Library

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I am developing app using beacons , my requirement is quite simple.
I need the list of beacons scanned for 5 seconds. Here I am creating two regions to added for ranging.

In didRangeBeacons(List), list I am getting is for only one region at a time. I need the list with the combination of these two regions.

Is there any possibility to combine these two regions, so that I can get List of beacons for both regions.

Can somebody help me to find solution for this. I learned Apple Doc but couldnt find any solution.

```
 /*

 This method is to Create Becon Region

 Function Input:- Array of UUID's Listed by API Call

 */



func createBeaconWithLocationUUIDString(beaconList:[Any]) {

    for beaconDUUID in beaconList {

        guard let documentValue = beaconDUUID as? String else {

            return

        }

        var uuidStringValue = documentValue

        uuidStringValue = uuidStringValue.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

        let proximityUUID = NSUUID.init(uuidString:uuidStringValue

        )

        let beaconID = "\(String(describing: proximityUUID?.uuidString))"

        guard proximityUUID != nil else{return}



        let  myBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: proximityUUID! as UUID,identifier: beaconID)



        myBeaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true

        myBeaconRegion.notifyOnExit = true

        myBeaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true

        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {

            locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: myBeaconRegion)

            locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(in: myBeaconRegion)

        }

    }

}
```